# PTR record on Google Cloud Vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP VM, i've assigned static internal and external IP's ... and a PTR Record, like this:

[image: network interface]

The usageconsulting.com domain is hosted at SquareSpace.

My intention is, when something on the internet accesses apigee-node1.usageconsulting.com, it will resolve to the external IP: 35.229.90.1

If this it the correct idea, then what do I need to ask for Squarespace to do to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The usageconsulting.com domain is hosted at SquareSpace.

All you need to do is log into your SquareSpace account, edit the DNS settings for `usageconsulting.com`, and [add an `A` record for `apigee-node1` pointing to `35.229.90.1`](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205812348-Advanced-DNS-settings).

You can uncheck the `PTR` record checkbox shown in your screenshot, as that's not what you're looking for (and requires domain verification steps which add a lot of work with no benefit to you).

For what it's worth, you don't need to make the internal IP static; the fact that the external IP is static is all that matters.

Comment: @SamUcich If my answer helped you, please **both** upvote **and** accept it (green check box). Thanks!